# what is the difference between a 40mm and 60 mm springs

Tags: honda, civic, suspension, shock-absorber

I have a '97 civic sedan.
I want to lower the front of my car and lift the rear, or keep it standard. 
now the body of the car is suspended a little higher than 100mm over the tyre of the car, but it seems low already.

I want the car lower, but not ridiculously low, a space should still exist between the wheels and the car, what is the higher option between a 40mm and 60mm spring? does the car get lowered 60mm, or will it be suspended 60mm over the wheel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know when to replace shock absorbers?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4031/how-do-i-know-when-to-replace-shock-absorbers)

Comment: there no more duplicate

Comment: That's much better. You do need to post single questions here, as multiple questions don't lead simply to single answers.

Comment: yup, but thanks to the downvote now my question is being ignored by people who could potentially answer my question, it's going to be a tumbleweed forever now

Comment: wups - my bad. I meant to remove my downvote. Done now.

Comment: thanks, howcome you can remove a downvote that long after? do you gain such a privilege beyond 2k rep?

Comment: You edited the post, that then means people can change their votes. I don't know if it is a time thing - I *think* it is purely down to the edit allows the vote change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking several on line vendors specs the 40mm or 60mm refers to the amount of lowering from stock. If your stock spring leaves 100mm of tire clearance a 40mm spring would leave 60 mm of clearance. Several things must be taken into account prior to selecting your springs. Your car may already be lower than stock due to the age and condition of the springs. The 40mm drop is from a new stock spring. If you add non stock tires and wheels the clearance will change. If you haven't done so recently I would suggest getting new struts as a leading cause of spring failure is worn struts. You will also need a front end alignment after installing the springs.

Comment: thanks, I was going to ask about the shocks' age as well

Answer (score -1):

There's really not enough information to accurately answer this question, but I'll try.

If you're talking about 40 mm or 60 mm as the spring diameter, the spring diameter affects the  spring rate. Assuming all other attributes of the spring are equal, such as length, number of coils, etc, then a 40 mm spring will have a lower spring rate than a 60 mm spring. A lower spring rate means that it will take less force to compress the spring a certain distance.

If you're describing 40 mm vs 60 mm as the height the spring lowers the car, then the difference is a 20 mm lower ride height.

Sorry for being so vague, but you really need to add more details. If you provide links to the specific brands you're talking about, that would help.

Comment: which one has the lower ride height? this what i meant, i thought people could figure so by me saying "I want the car lower, but not ridiculously low". I know they have a difference of 20mm, I can tell. . .as should anyone, but i'm not sure whether that relates to ride height or not.

Comment: Which springs are you looking at?

Comment: eibach probably. . .